# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Nvidia MX150 stopped working after a kernel upgrade

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I have searched the forums and googled.  I have tried many different permutations of kernels and nvidia drivers but unable to make Nvidia Mx150 work with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

My system was working fine with the Nvidia Mx150 graphics driver (with cuda) but then I did a random kernel update and it broke the Nvidia MX150 drivers.  I went ahead with the Intel display drivers because Cuda wasn't necessary.

But now I need Cuda again and tried to install Nvidia drivers for Mx150 again.  However I am unable to with my current kernel: 4.18.0-041800-generic

I tried to use Nvidia driver 460 and 455.

I also tried to downgrade my kernel to 4.15.0.23.25 and it didn't work.

I tried to "nvidia-drm.modeset=1" in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in the /etc/default/grub
and update-grub but it didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution? or does anyone have it currently working with MX150 on Ubuntu?

I know this will work with some combination of kernel version and nvidia version.
So if someone can help me resolve this? or just tell me the kernel version+nvidia driver version they have this working , I can try to replicate that?

thank you
A

Comment: I would try to install the latest supported kernel version from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. As of today, it should be  4.15.0-133.137 or  5.4.0.62.70~18.04.57, and, by the way, automatic updates should take care of that. Don't install random kernels, my kernels or the next door neighbor's kernels.

Comment: Installing kernel in the 5.4X range causes other problems with my Acer E5 laptop. 
 
Wouldn't 4.18X be more latest than the one you suggested?

By 'random kernel' update, I did mean it was automatic update.

Comment: How is it, that you are at kernel 4.18.0-041800-generic, with autoupdate enabled? Where does it come from? Support for 4.18x ended sometime in 2019, and I doubt packages are still in the repositories. PS: You've probably meant routine update, not random.

Comment: Yes, correct.  I think at one point it got auto updated to 5.X, which started the problems. I think I tried to downgrade to 4.X.. probably I screwed up at that point.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to backup and reinstall, given the circumstances. If Ubuntu 18.04 is the choice, and you wish to stay with kernel version 4.15x, then start with installing from [18.04 or 18.04.1 image](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/).

Comment: You're probably right.. I was hoping someone could tell me about a working combination of kernel and nvidia driver, which I  could try, but re-install maybe the only way